# On the subject of delimiters

Tags: java, delimiter

I’m new to Java and was just wondering , with the default delimiter, what will be the value of age? (Note i enter the values when prompted and then end with a ‘enter’ key)

Enter Age: 14 45 20 16 (then press enter key)

What is the value of age( 14? 16? 14452016?) and why?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please come up with a code that you have tried.

Comment: How are you reading those values? If you don't share your code, no one will be able to answer this question.

Comment: Are you using a notebook and a pen to process all those entries?

Comment: Hey everyone, my bad I just noticed how I didn’t include the code I used. It was basically using Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); so since the default delimeter is a white space, whatever the first value is (14 in this case) will be stored correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about `java.util.Scanner`, the default delimiter is whitespace. Therefore, if you enter "14 45 20 16" on the command line and then pressed the enter key, the `nextInt` or `next` call on the scanner instance would return 14. If you then call `nextInt` on scanner again, you get no prompting; that would immediately return 45. Another 2 calls would return respectively 20 and 16. If you then call `nextInt` a fifth time, that call would wait until you typed something.